# If $\gamma$ is a circle and $\int_0^{2\pi}y(t) \, dt =0$ then $y(t)=a \sin t + b\cos t$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, curves, plane-curves, integral-inequality

I'm reading a paper on the isoperimetric theorem and I can't figure something out. Let $\gamma=(x(t),y(t))$, where
$x(t)=-\int_0^t y(s) \, ds$, and $y(t)$ is a smooth function of period $2\pi$ such that $\int_0^{2\pi}y(t) \, dt=0$. It follows that $x(t)$ is also of period $2\pi$, so $\gamma$ is a smooth closed curve. It is then shown that
$$x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2=c^2 $$
where $c\in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant, and that $L=2\pi c$ where $L$ is the length of $\gamma$. It is also known that $\gamma$ must be a circumference and that
$$\int_0^{2\pi}y'(t)^2 \, dt = \int_0^{2\pi} y(t)^2 \, dt$$
Take everything I said up until now as hypothesis. Now the bit I don't get: the author says that $\int_0^{2\pi}y(t) \, dt = 0$ easily implies that $y(t)=a \sin t + b \cos t$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Why is this true?

Comment: This is true because only the trigonometric functions sine and cosine have this property. You can verify this by integrating them for the same limits as the intgeral. Other trigonometric functions also have this property, but as their Cauchy Principal Value for the integral you talked about.

Comment: I need to show that using the information I put in the post, even if this is a known fact. Could you please give more details?

Comment: It is simple. You can just integrate the function.